# Skype Camera on Android

Tags: skype

I am using Android TV Box 4.4 which has features like a Tablet.Whenever I am using Skype, voice is O.K but the camera other party see is very dark,I have tried different versions of Skype … but problem remains same. When I am not using webcam on Skype, the camera separately is very fine and works normally. I really appreciate if somebody help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I believe this has something to do with the network speed and your router.
so try changing to better network.

Answer (score 0):

I find Skype to be very poorly optimized, especially for video.

Maybe you should try other alternatives to Skype for video like Hangout or Tango? Just to be able to see if you will be getting the same issues as you do with Skype. If you do, then it means you have issues with your network.

Comment: As I told you that my webcam separately working fine, but only when you are using Skype, the camera is dark.